# Algorithm: Factorize a integer X to get as many distinct positive integers(Y1...Yk) as possible so that (Y1+1)(Y2+1)...(Yk+1) = X

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, prime-factoring, factorization

I recently met a algorithm question in open.kattis.com.
The question's link is https://open.kattis.com/problems/listgame2.
Basically, it is a question ask the players to factorize a integer X (10^3 <= X <= 10^15) to get as many **distinct** positive integers (Y<sub>1</sub>,...,Y<sub>k</sub>) as possible such that (Y<sub>1</sub>+1)(Y<sub>2</sub>+1)⋯(Y<sub>k</sub>+1) = X.

I already came up with a solution using Python3, which does pass several test cases but failed one of them:[MyStatus](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz0mn.png)

My code is:

```
def minFactor(n, start):
    maxFactor = round(n**0.5)
    for i in range(start, maxFactor+1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return i
    return n

def distinctFactors(n):
    curMaxFactor = 1
    factors = []

    while n > 1:
        curMaxFactor = minFactor(n, curMaxFactor+1)
        n //= curMaxFactor
        factors.append(curMaxFactor)

    # This is for the situation where the given number is the square of a prime number
    # For example, when the input is 4, the returned factors would be [2,2] instead of [4]
    # The if statement below are used to fix this flaw
    # And since the question only requires the length of the result, deleting the last factor when repeat do works in my opinion
    if factors[-1] in factors[:-1]:
        del factors[-1]

    return factors

num = int(input())
print(len(distinctFactors(num)))
```

Specifically, my idea inside the above code is quite simple. For example, when the given input is 36, I run the minFactor function to find that the minimum factor of 36 is 2 (1 is ignored in this case). Then, I get 18 by doing 36/2 and invoke minFactor(18,3) since 2 is no more distinct so I start to find the minimum factor of 18 by 3. And it is 3 clearly, so I get 6 by doing 18/3 in function distinctFactors and invoke minFactor(6,4), since 4 is smaller than sqrt(6) or 6**0.5 so 6 itself will be returned and I finally get the list factors as [2,3,6], which is correct.

I have scrutinised my code and algorithm for hours but I still cannot figure out why I failed the test case, could anyone help me with my dilemma??? Waiting for reply.

Comment: There's no guarantee that always picking the smallest factor is optimal (or even that it produces a valid solution with no duplicate factors).

Comment: @user2357112, but I think considering from the smallest factor can give me with the longest list factors...I think every time I want  to get something as many as possible I start with the smallest case...so could you please give me an example or an detailed explanation about your idea, many thx~

Comment: The largest set of factors is given by the *prime factorisation* of `X`. Then for each repeated factor, compute the maximal non-repeating set. e.g. 24 = 2^3 * 3 = 2 * 4 * 3. This could be done using dynamic programming

Comment: @meowgoesthedog: There's no reason to expect that to produce an optimal set either. For example, it fails on Peter de Rivaz's example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the number `2**6.11**5`.

Your algorithm will find 5 factors:

```
2
2**2
2**3
11
11**2
(11**2 this will be discarded as it is a repeat)
```

A 6 length answer is:

```
2
2**2
11
11**2
2*11
2**2*11
```

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for the counterexample！I now am aware of my mistake. It seems that I went wrong at the very beginning when I started to think about this question:( Btw, could you give me some hints about the correct direction or something about how you will deal with this question? Thx again~