# Is there a method/Algorithm to generate unique integers from prime factors of a given number?

Tags: python, algorithm, primes, number-theory

I'm trying to solve the following question https://open.kattis.com/problems/listgame2
and I am successfully able to generate all the prime factors of a given number but the problem demands that I need to get a list of unique numbers only.

for example - 
1099511627776 = 2^40
but since the number 2 is repeated 40 times, the problem is to simplify 2^40 as 2*4*8* .... == 1099511627776 without repeating any integers to arrive that the product.

I found a similar question on Stackoverflow at [Algorithm: Factorize a integer X to get as many distinct positive integers(Y1...Yk) as possible so that (Y1+1)(Y2+1)...(Yk+1) = X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46654759/algorithm-factorize-a-integer-x-to-get-as-many-distinct-positive-integersy1)
but there was no logic provided

A counter example from the above link is the number 10307264 = 2^6 * 11^5 this should possibly reduce to 2 * 4 * 11*  22 * 44 * 121 == 10307264

I don't seek a solution but rather a discussion towards a concrete logic to find the optimal solution.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stop thinking of these as unique integers; think of them as tuples of powers.  Your first example is 2^40; you have to partition `40` into as many distinct integers as possible.  For this simple example, a greedy approach makes it trivial: you grab 1, then 2, ... until the remaining number isn't large enough to separate without stepping on a previous number.  This is a simple application of triangle numbers:

```
`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`, and a remainder of 4
```

... that you can distribute among the upper numbers as you see fit (without duplication); you will get 8 distinct integers for your score.  For instance:  `1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9` are the powers of 2 you might want.

For a complex number, such as 2^6 11^5, you now have a pair `(6, 5)` to partition into distinct pairs.  Now, you can have 0 components, so long as no pair is entirely 0.  Your given 5-opint solution is sub-optimal; the linked question gives 6, represented by the power pairs

```
1 0
2 0
0 1
0 2
1 1
2 1
```

Giving us six 2s and 5 11s.

This is where a multi-dimansional solution comes in handy.  The given solution is formed from the product of available small factors (again greedy) for 2 and 11:

```
{0 1 2} x {0 1 2}
```

... taking the least-cost choice at each juncture.  Imagine this as a lattice in 2D space.  Starting near the origin, we work outward through the lattice, consuming the least-cost point each time.  "Least-cost" is the choice the leaves us the greatest range of options.  I'll number the axes and label the choices in order:

```
11 \ 2  0  1  2
  0        A  C
  1     B  E  F  
  2     D
```

There are various ways to work at "least-cost": fewest factors consumed (i.e. lowest tuple sum), greatest remaining product of powers (i.e. we take 2^1 first, because that leaves 5x5 factors, rather than 4x6 if we'd taken 11^1).

If recursion appeals to you, then you can write a simple recursive routine that iterates through the inner shell of the N-dim space, considering all of the tuples adjacent to the points already consumed (including the disqualified origin).  Each choice leaves a separable, independent sub-problem.  BTW, it's trivial to prove that this "inner shell" is sufficient to find the optimal solution.

For instance, in the above (6 5) examples, the two inner-shell points to try are (1 0) and (0 1), leaving sub-problems of (5 5) and (6 4).  It's easy to see that the solution paths will converge: I strongly suggest that, if you attack this solution, that you memoize your results (dynamic programming) to avoid duplication.

---

Does that get you moving?